# Loading a javascript alert onload without preventing the

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to load an alert that redirects to another page, but the problem is the background of the page doesn't load. The only html to be rendered is the javascript alert. Any idea how to fix this so that at least some of the html loads before the alert?

also tried

```
var onFooEndFunc = function() 
{
    var delay = 50; /* milliseconds - vary as desired */
    var executionTimer;

    return function() 
    {
        if (executionTimer) 
        {
            clearTimeout(executionTimer);
        }

        executionTimer = setTimeout(function() 
        {
            window.alert('Please download a game');
            window.location.href='games.html';
        }, delay);
    };
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged using jQuery, you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.alert('Please download a game')
  window.location.href='games.html';
});
```

Or natively:

```
window.onload=function(){
  window.alert('Please download a game')
  window.location.href='games.html';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Popup is what you need

just set a div

```
<div id="popup_download">
  Please download a game!
    <a href="game1.exe">Mario</a>
     <a href="game2.exe">Sonice Rider</a>
</div>
```

at style set display:hidden

```
#popup_download
{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    top:200px;
    left:50%;
    width:500px; 
    margin-left:-250px;
    border:1px solid blue; 
    padding:20px;
    background-color:white;
}
```

when page is loaded just set `display:block`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_popup()
    {
      document.getElementById('popup_download').style.display = 'block'; 
    }

    window.onload = show_popup;
</script>
```

The benefit of it is you can add any HTML elements,css and even php or asp or any code inside and your background will continue working.